# "Our trade and commerce has..." Is that correct?

Tags: verbs

Mr Obama said "Our trade and commerce has expanded significantly." Should it be "our trade and commerce have..."? He also said "The US and Uruguay has developed..." As same as previous one, should that sentence be like "The US and Uruguay have developed.."? Thank you for addressing my question.

Comment: Like many mortal beings, President Obama commits small errors when speaking extemporaneously.

Comment: It is a common error, perhaps increasingly common and perhaps a sign of changing language, but strictly speaking it should be "have".

Comment: To add to @Rob_Ster's comment: President Obama, in these situations, has to monitor his word choice in real time to ensure that he is using plain and simple language (so as to minimize the chance that his meaning is lost in translation). This extra linguistic constraint may result in awkward phrasing or incorrect grammar.

Comment: It's also possible to think of _trade and commerce_ as a single collective. But that's not an excuse for the US and Uruguay quote.

Comment: In the first case the term could be considered a single "collective" term, as Barmar suggests.  In the second case I can't think of a reasonable "excuse", other than the one that Kyle proposes.  All-in-all, Mr Obama is quite impressive at speaking "off the cuff", and it's hard to fault him in such cases as these.  I doubt that many people could do nearly as well.

Answer (score 1):

I answered a similar question a few hours ago, [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/312603/should-i-use-the-plural-after-a-disjunctive-or/312619#312619).

This is technically vague, and if he were going to use PERFECT English, he would have used the word 'both' and changed the verb tense to 'have expanded.'

```
 Both our trade and commerce have expanded significantly.
```

Alternatively, if we consider 'trade and commerce' to be a single classification or entity, he could have used them as adjectives to describe a noun that denotes their collective nature (such as *arena* or *division*). Example:

```
 Our trade and commerce arena has expanded significantly.
```

That being said, I think he gets a free pass on this one, considering that his biggest errors are more correct and intelligent than George W. Bush's most eloquent speeches.